# How to update Laravel session Id in testing

Tags: laravel, testing, session

How can I make the get request load with its session id as what is initially created with `$sessionId = session()->getId();`

```
public function test_chatbot_messages_page_has_non_empty_chat(): void
{
    $sessionId = session()->getId();

    ChatbotMessage::create([
        'session_id' => $sessionId,
        'content' => 'Hello',
        'role' => 'You',
    ]);

    ChatbotMessage::create([
        'session_id' => $sessionId,
        'content' => 'Hi there',
        'role' => 'Bot',
    ]);

    $response = $this->get(route('chatbot-messages.index'));

    $response->assertSee('Hello');
}
```

`Index` method of the above `route`

```
 public function index()
  {
    $conversationHistory = ChatbotMessage::select(['content', 'role'])
      ->where('session_id', session()
        ->getId())
      ->get();

    return view('chatbot-messages.index', compact('conversationHistory'));
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried `withSession` [method](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-tests#session-and-authentication) ?

Comment: @RamyHerrira Yes, and maybe I'm not using it correctly. This is what I did. 
    
`$this->withSession(['session_id' => $sessionId])get(route('chatbot-messages.index'));`

Comment: Your test is still missing an assertion, you are not asserting anything. I had never had to manipulate the session ID like you need to, so I am not sure how easy it is going to be for you, but first complete the test and then we can fully help

Comment: @matiaslauriti  tried to keep it simple, I've updated it. The route loads messages where the session id matches the session id of the current user.

Comment: Usually, when testing something as basic as this is hell on earth means that you are taking a wrong approach, it is a very good code smell. May I know why are you using the `session_id` that is never the same (when you log out and log in, you have a new session id)? Why not `user_id`?

Comment: Sure, I have a simple chatbot with no signup required. When a user chats with the bot, I save their messages and replies along with their session IDs. This allows me to show a user the conversations that belong to them, even when they refresh the page or close and reopen the browser. I have updated the question and added my `index` method to shed more light on this.

Comment: @AlphyGacheru makes sense. I honestly am a little bit ignorant in general about sessions (and I hate them), but using the `session_id` for tracking purposes makes sense. I cannot remember now when the ID refreshes, but I get what the usage is going to be.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I was able to find a solution. I've shared it in the answers section. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution. This is what worked for me.

```
  public function test_chatbot_messages_page_has_non_empty_chat()
  {
    $sessionId = session()->getId();
    $sessionName = session()->getName();

    $userMessage = ChatbotMessage::create([
      'session_id' => $sessionId,
      'content' => 'Hello',
      'role' => 'You'
    ]);

    $chatbotMessage = ChatbotMessage::create([
      'session_id' => $sessionId,
      'content' => 'Hi there',
      'role' => 'Bot'
    ]);

    $response = $this->withCookies([$sessionName => $sessionId])
                     ->get(route('chatbot-messages.index'));

    $response->assertViewHas('conversationHistory', function ($collection) use ($userMessage, $chatbotMessage) {
      return $collection->contains('content', $userMessage['content'])
        && $collection->contains('content', $chatbotMessage['content'])
        && $collection->contains('role', $userMessage['role'])
        && $collection->contains('role', $chatbotMessage['role']);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to using session()->setId($sessionId), you set the session ID for the test session to match the one you created initially. This way, when you make the GET request in your test, it will use the same session ID, and your index method will retrieve the chat history associated with that session.

```
// Set the session ID for the test session
session()->setId($sessionId);

$response = $this->get(route('chatbot-messages.index'));

$response->assertSee('Hello');
```

But I'm not sure if you were thinking about that.

Comment: That will still regenerate another session id when you make the get request.